# How can i add the output of my craps code to an array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

How can i add the output of my craps code to the array my_list?
I would like the final output to look like:

```
1's: {No. Of One's}
2's: {No. Of Two's}
3's: {No. Of Three's}
4's: {No. Of Four's}
```

Obviously after it prints the games output
i tried adding the append to array line to the bottom and then the print my_list to do it so it runs after however that didnt work

My code looks like this:

```
my_list = []
for i in range(1,2):
    def RollDice():
        import random
        d1 = random.randint(1, 6)
        d2 = random.randint(1, 6)
        return int(d1 + d2)


    def ComeOutRoll():
        print('Come-Out Roll')
        roll = RollDice()
        if roll in [7, 11]:
            print('You win!')
        elif roll in [2,3,12]:
            # craps lose
            print('Craps! You lose!')
        elif roll in [4,5,6,8,9,10]:
            # the point
            print('Point %d' % roll)
            Finished = False
            while not Finished: Finished = ReRoll(roll)

    def ReRoll(point):
        roll = RollDice()
        print(' Roll: %d' % (roll))
        if not roll in [7, point]:
            # lose
            print('Roll again!')
        elif roll in [point]:
            # point match
            print('Point-Match')
        elif roll in [7]:
            # seven-out lose
            # game over
            print('Seven-Out!\nYou lose!\nGame Over!')
            return True
        return False

    ComeOutRoll()
    my_list.append(RollDice)
print(my_list)

Output:

Come-Out Roll
You win!
[<function RollDice at 0x000000CAEFAAFAE8>]
```

Comment: You want to know how many times it the dice rolls a specific number?

Comment: You're appending the method to your list instead of the results of calling it  ( you're missing your parenthesis )

Comment: I want to print out how many times each number is printed so for example print 1 : 4 as if the number one was used 4 times

Comment: How do i fix that? Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
my_list = []
my_num = []
for i in range(1,2):
def RollDice():
    import random
    d1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    d2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    UpdArray(d1)
    UpdArray(d2)
    return int(d1+d2)
def UpdArray(x):
    my_num.append(x)
def ComeOutRoll():
    print('Come-Out Roll')
    roll = RollDice()
    if roll in [7, 11]:
        print('You win!')
    elif roll in [2,3,12]:
        # craps lose
        print('Craps! You lose!')
    elif roll in [4,5,6,8,9,10]:
        # the point
        print('Point %d' % roll)
        Finished = False
        while not Finished: Finished = ReRoll(roll)

def ReRoll(point):
    roll = RollDice()
    print(' Roll: %d' % (roll))
    if not roll in [7, point]:
        # lose
        print('Roll again!')
    elif roll in [point]:
        # point match
        print('Point-Match')
    elif roll in [7]:
        # seven-out lose
        # game over
        print('Seven-Out!\nYou lose!\nGame Over!')
        return True
    return False

ComeOutRoll()
my_list.append(RollDice())
print(my_list)
print("req. ", my_num)

for x in set(my_num):
    print(x,"'s", my_num.count(x), "\n" )
```

Sample output:

```
Come-Out Roll
Point 10
Roll: 7
Seven-Out!
You lose!
Game Over!
[9]
req. [4, 6, 6, 1, 3, 6]
1 's 1
3 's 1
4 's 1
6 's 3
```

Comment: This was probably my fault, id like it so it prints How many of each numbers which have been rolled by the program in a collumn so : 1ns : 3 2s : 4 ect but below each other